# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

Can anyone help me with this error. It works when I try the first procedure but not the second when I enter two numbers. Any ideas?

```
create or replace package LE2_P1
is
procedure GENERATE_MULTIPLICATION_TABLE(p_axis_both in number);
procedure GENERATE_MUTLIPLICATION_TABLE(p_axis_x in number, p_axis_y in number);
end LE2_P1;
/

create or replace package body LE2_P1
as
procedure GENERATE_MULTIPLICATION_TABLE(p_axis_both in number)
is
bb number := 1;
eb number := p_axis_both;
begin
for xyz in 1 .. eb loop
for xyx in 1 .. eb loop
dbms_output.put(CHR(9) || to_char(xyz * (bb + xyx - 1)));
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(CHR(13) || CHR(10));
end loop;
end GENERATE_MULTIPLICATION_TABLE;
procedure GENERATE_MUTLIPLICATION_TABLE(p_axis_x in number, p_axis_y in number)
is
bb number := p_axis_x;
eb number:= p_axis_y;
begin
for xyz in 1 .. eb loop
for xyx in 1 .. eb loop
dbms_output.put(CHR(9) || to_char(xyz * (bb + xyx - 1)));
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(CHR(13) || CHR(10));
end loop;
end GENERATE_MUTLIPLICATION_TABLE;

end LE2_P1;
/

declare
x number := 5;
y number := 3;
begin
LE2_P1.GENERATE_MULTIPLICATION_TABLE(x,y);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure with two arguments' name is typoed: MU **T L** IPLICATION

Answer (score 1):

OracleParameter[] pr=new OracleParameter[20];
            pr[1]=new OracleParameter("IN_BILL_COMPCD_C",OracleType.VarChar);
            pr[1].Value=IN_BILL_COMPCD_C;
            pr[1]=new OracleParameter("IN_BILL_BRCD_C",OracleType.VarChar);
            pr[1].Value=IN_BILL_BRCD_C;

Two Parameter passed in single value. that's why arrive this error.